# Redirect mouse events to QMenu/QMenuBar window

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm making a MenuBar, but when a submenu is open, I can't press the window's X button, plus the menu closes when I press outside of it. I plan to ignore all mouse events that occur in the menu.

It seems that it is because the events are completely redirected to the menubar. Therefore, installEventFilter and virtual functions may have had no effect on this issue.

I also tried `menu.releaseMouse` and `menu.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)`, without success.

Is there a way to redirect the mouse events to the window, or so that the X button can be pressed without closing the menu?

Below is some code that will be used to create a test menu:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()

files = menu.addMenu("Files")
files.addAction("hello")
files.addAction("world")

menu.showMaximized()

app.exec_()
```

additional details:

- The menu is part of the main window
- The plan is for my program to be controlled almost entirely with the keyboard, and to avoid the use of the mouse.
- Separators cannot be pressed or selected.
- Preferably, the main menu will be a horizontal bar
- There will not be any other widget in the main window. This, together with the almost total absence of the mouse, will prevent accidents.

**A little context** (sorry if it's noise, but I saw that it's necessary): I'm looking to recreate a tui written in an obsolete language called Clipper, and instead of rethinking the entire interface, I wanted to adapt my way of programming to a terminal program (motivated by personal reasons). I know the irony of choosing a gui module for a tui, but the reality is that the terminal is harder to manage and I need Qt's printing capabilities anyway, so why not?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following: you want to be able to interact with other elements (including the ability to close the window) while still keeping the menu open? Maybe you could try the tear off functions of QMenu, like [`showTearOffMenu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#showTearOffMenu).

Comment: @musicamante It's almost what I'm looking for, except that it's going to be my main window and I require at least the minimize and maximize buttons (WindowFlags don't work) and, preferably, that the first menu be horizontal. Thanks, I'll do more research on what you said to see if I make the points above.

Comment: I suggest you to add more details about your requirements, and also seriously consider what users *expect* from common and well established conventions: clicking *anywhere else* to close a menu is what any user would expect, knowing that the click won't affect any other objects. Forcing the user to be more careful about an unexpected behavior may not be a good choice. Also be aware that forcing window flags may have other unexpected results depending on the OS, and it's important to be *extremely* aware of the possible consequences.

Comment: @musicamante I'm using old conventions, and the target users are used to them. But you would be right under normal circumstances. And about the flags, thanks for letting me know, but it seems that most of them work the same in various operating systems. Anyway, based on your proposal, I am making the tearoff menu as a window widget. Although I still have to see some things.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the menus are actually internally separate windows. Playing with it for a while, I found that changing the flags, turning the menus into windows without frames of said windows almost completely solves the problem.

```
class Menu(QtWidgets.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Now, the menus don't close when clicked (that was one of the things I wanted to achieve), but if someone wants them to close it's as simple as adding to the end of the constructor

```
self.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

Which closes the window (by calling close) when an action is executed

The following code implements the mentioned

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class Menu(QtWidgets.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.triggered.connect(self.close)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

menu = window.menuBar()

for name in ["Files", "Edit"]:
    files = Menu(name)
    files.addAction("hello", lambda:print("hello"))
    files.addAction("world", lambda:print("world"))
    menu.addMenu(files)

window.setMenuBar(menu)
window.showMaximized()

app.exec_()
```

**Note** Unfortunately, I don't know if this is cross-platform or if it has optimization implications. I invite any user to extend this answer.

**Edit** Changed the Window flag to the Dialog flag so that the menu does not appear as another window on the taskbar.

**Edit 2** Implemented Musicamante's advice to use Qt.Tool to improve compatibility between platforms

Comment: You may want to consider `Qt.Tool` instead of `Qt.Dialog`, which should work for most systems.